# MS Access CREATE TABLE "WITH COMPRESSION" syntax?

Tags: ms-access, ddl

I'm trying to write a `CREATE TABLE` statement for Microsoft Access (to be executed via a C# / .NET app using an OleDbConnection), utilizing the `WITH COMPRESSION` attribute to cause character columns (TEXT) to be created using single-byte characters rather than Unicode double-byte characters, as documented on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837200.aspx).

> The WITH COMPRESSION attribute can be used only with the CHARACTER and MEMO (also known as TEXT) data types and their synonyms.
>
> The WITH COMPRESSION attribute was added for CHARACTER columns because of the change to the Unicode character representation format. Unicode characters uniformly require two bytes for each character. For existing Microsoft® Jet databases that contain predominately character data, this could mean that the database file would nearly double in size when converted to the Microsoft Access database engine format. However, Unicode representation of many character sets, those formerly denoted as Single-Byte Character Sets (SBCS) can easily be compressed to a single byte. If you define a CHARACTER column with this attribute, data will automatically be compressed as it is stored and uncompressed when retrieved from the column.

When I try to execute the following statement (which I believe to be syntactically correct per MSDN) via an OleDbConnection, I get a syntax error.

```
CREATE TABLE [Foo] ([COL1] TEXT(255) WITH COMPRESSION)
```

Likewise, executing the same statement directly within MS Access 2013 as a query gives a syntax error at `WITH`.

Executing

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute("CREATE TABLE [Foo1] ([COL1] TEXT(255) WITH COMPRESSION)")
```

from Access VBA *does* work, however.

If I take out the `WITH COMPRESSION` attribute, the statement executes without error both via OleDb and directly in MS Access.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I get no error when executing your `CREATE TABLE` statement with `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute` in Access 2010.  Then, with that table in Design View, the field's *Unicode Compression* property is *True*, as expected.  Is there more to your error message than just *"syntax error"*?

Comment: I'm not using VBA or any coding within Access - I'm using C# and an OleDbConnection. But I get the same error if I create a new query in MS Access, go to the "SQL View" and try to run the CREATE TABLE statement above.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong in your C# project. [This code](http://pastebin.com/QYXC1FvY) works just fine for me.

Comment: Thanks @GordThompson - that code works for me as well; I'll dig into my app and figure out what I'm doing wrong. When I got the same syntax error running the query directly in Access, I stopped looking at my code...

Comment: Turned out to be a different syntax error on my part... I should have spent more time playing in my code. Thanks again @GordThompson for throwing that sample together and getting me pointed the right direction...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem turned out to be a syntax error that wasn't reflected properly in my original question.

However, solving that problem revealed that the documentation for MS Access `CREATE TABLE` on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837200.aspx is incorrect regarding the sequence of attributes for the CREATE TABLE statement. According to the documentation, the syntax is:

> CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE table (field1 type [(size)] [NOT NULL] [WITH COMPRESSION | WITH COMP] [index1] [, field2 type [(size)] [NOT NULL] [index2] [, …]] [, CONSTRAINT multifieldindex [, …]])

but in fact, `[WITH COMPRESSION | WITH COMP]` must appear *before* `[NOT NULL]` or you get a syntax error.

Additionally, it's not possible to execute the `CREATE TABLE` statement using the `WITH COMPRESSION` attribute from a query directly within MS Access. You have to either use VBA or (as in my case) an external program via `OleDbConnection`.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with "WITH COMPRESSION" and MS-ACCESS 2013
Impossible to run such a script from query window.
Possible from VBA but with limitations:

`currentdb.Execute` "... WITH COMPRESSION" -> "Syntax error in CREATE
   TABLE" `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute` " ..." - > Ok

I confirm what "Mr. T" says: WITH COMPRESSION **must appear** before NOT NULL

Comment: It must also be TEXT and not for example CHAR... otherwise the Unicode compression also doesn't work.